pyTorch: annotation "@torch.jit.export" doesn't work
I tried to build "*.pth" file for android , the file is generated successfully, however, when i call the function "inference", there is a problem:
AttributeError: 'RecursiveScriptModule' object has no attribute 'inference'
This is my code:
def optimizeSave(model, model_folder):
    # Scripting the entire model
    scripted_module = torch.jit.script(model)
    # scripted_inference_method = torch.jit.script_method(model.inference)
    # scripted_module.inference = scripted_inference_method
    scripted_module_optimized = optimize_for_mobile(scripted_module)
    scripted_module_optimized._save_for_lite_interpreter(f"{model_folder}/inference.pt")


class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()


    def forward(self, x):
        return x

    @torch.jit.export
    def inference(self, x: str)->str:
        # Dummy implementation for string processing, normally you'd do some tensor operations
        return f"Processed string: {x}"


model = MyModel()
model.eval()
optimizeSave(model, "models")
print("finished")

optimized_model = torch.jit.load("models/inference.pt")
print(optimized_model.inference("hell world"))

Anyone know why?

"hell world" lol. Maybe try this out: optimize_for_mobile(scripted_module, preserved_methods=["inference"]), mobile optimizer documentation, here's someone else having a similar issue

Hi @BrockBrown, It's a very good guess. Actually, I tried to run the 'inference.pt' model on Android. After modifying the code to optimize using optimize_for_mobile(scripted_module, preserved_methods=["inference"]), the code works in Python. However, it still doesn't work on Android. I checked the link you shared, but it doesn't seem to provide a solution. I've posted another link question here - do you have any idea how to solve this issue?"
